# What is the issue with the javascript code?

Tags: javascript

```
 var titleModel = function () {
    this.title = ko.observable("test");
    this.desc = ko.observable("test");
    return
    {
        title: this.title,
        desc: this.desc
    }
}
```

The above code is a model where i want to give access only title,desc from return function only. However, it says a ';' is required. I think the syntax is correct.

However, if i remove the return all works correctly.

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what the issue is.

Comment: The problem is the JavaScript `;` autocompletion - see answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the object on the same line. `return` is strange like that.

```
var titleModel = function () {
    this.title = ko.observable("test");
    this.desc = ko.observable("test");
    return {
        title: this.title,
        desc: this.desc
    }; // semicolon here.
}; // semicolon here.
```

Comment: No, it's not that `return` is strange - it's that JavaScript is strange and adds `;` for you on every new line where it can. In this case it can as it would still be valid code.

Answer (score 1):

Move the starting brace on the same line as the return.

```
return { ..
...
}
```

If not the return is considered as a separate line. This is because the terminating semicolon is optional in javascript ([What are the rules for Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)).

Comment: *And* because `return` is a valid statement by itself.